# Mongo REPL storing result in var?

Tags: mongodb, read-eval-print-loop

Curious -- in the following example, why does the mongo REPL not store the user hash in variable 'a' past the first print?

Does it have something to do with mongo's lazy query evaluation?

```
> var a = db.users.find(0)
> a
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4eed6dc299cd67e275000001"), "provider" : "facebook", "uid" : "343323487", "name" : "Brian Jordan", "email" : "redacted@redacted.com" }
> a
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findOne`.

```
> var a = db.testcoll.findOne()
> a
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4e7930a3ff647405d6000003"),
    "bf" : false,
    "df" : ISODate("2011-09-21T00:32:35.629Z")
}
```

Or you can look at its source and do something similar

```
> db.testcoll.findOne
function (query, fields) {
    var cursor = this._mongo.find(this._fullName, this._massageObject(query) || {}, fields, -1, 0, 0, 0);
    if (!cursor.hasNext()) {
        return null;
    }
    var ret = cursor.next();
    if (cursor.hasNext()) {
        throw "findOne has more than 1 result!";
    }
    if (ret.$err) {
        throw "error " + tojson(ret);
    }
    return ret;
}
```